# Auto-Resize + Transform Rotation ==> What is the most elegant solution to make it work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autoresize

Hi fellow software engineers, I am in need of great help :)
Thanks in advance for your help!

**Here is my issue :**

VIEW B which is contained in VIEW A

VIEW B has auto-resize with all options `([.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin])`   as I want VIEW B to resize with VIEW A if VIEW A's height changes.

[image]
[image]

Until now it works...VIEW B is moved and resized correctly BUT when I have a transform rotate applied on VIEW B, and I try the same height change of VIEW A.

**Here is what happens :**

[image]
[image]

I have been suggested to manually set the frames of each views in VIEW A when I change its size. But I find it very "**Mc Gyverish**", considering the fact that VIEW A can contain a lot of views like VIEW B

Comment: Please do not use caps in title.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior for the `autoresizingMask`. Use `Autolayout` for solving of this issue. It is more common way that will work perfectly in common cases like you describe.

Also `Autolayout` and `autoresizingMask` are not same.

Constraints:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
By setting width and height with constraints like you did, the view is not changing its height with the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

use autolayout and resizing altogether.
Below is the method you could try.

**Step 1:**
Do autolayout. (Depends on the postion of your red view.Mine is right and top constraint)

**Step 2:**
Do autoresizing.

Right click red view and drop the cursor to the main view and select equal width and equal height.
[image]

and from attribute inspector change size by putting multiplier.
[image]

I have change my redView's width with aspect ratio value 0.6.

using this technique and redView will be easily adjustable according to device size.

Just for addition if you want to animate using constraint change 
Always use

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

just like this

```
-(void)rotate {
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.redView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    }];
    self.redView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

There are some useful stack answer why do we need this.May be you can google it if you want to know the reason. :)